# Vanguard Four Fund Portfolio

Tags: vanguard

I have been a huge fan of vanguard index funds ever since I was 15 years old. I remember saving up my allowance and minimum wage job to make the $3,000 minimum investment in the s&p 500. My question is whether my portfolio is set up for long-term success. I've heard about John Bogle's three fund portfolio and after hearing Dave Ramsey go on about smug 12% returns I'm just wondering if I'm set up properly? I don't mind market swings and I'm fine with buying and holding for the long-term. I usually buy more when the market is in decline.

- VFIAX 24%
- VTSAX 51%
- VTIAX 19%
- VBTLX 5%

I figured owning VTSAX pretty much covers me for all angles of growth, growth and income, international, and aggressive growth. Should I be looking at sec yields or are there better vanguard funds to be invested in?